# 20 gaps problem when using blockchain'receive API

Tags: java

The problem is the same with the following url:
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48090/how-to-solve-blockchain-20-address-gap-limit-problem

that's to say,if no money was send to the address and happend more than 20 times, no new address would be generated by blockchain.

The guy point out one solution: send money to some address already exists.

But, where could I find the exists address? wallet?(I only find 2 )

Any other good suggestion if you are add btc payment in one website?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Tor has nothing to do with Bitcoin.

Comment: It seems to be a wrong place.